# CouchDB pagination and sorting

Tags: sorting, pagination, couchdb

So I am using this approach on CouchDB docs to perform pagination.

- Request rows_per_page + 1 rows from the view
- Display rows_per_page rows, store + 1 row as next_startkey and next_startkey_docid
- As page information, keep startkey and next_startkey
- Use the next_* values to
  create the next link, and use the others to create the previous link

One thing I don't understand is, how do I perform sorting using this approach, assuming each document have a last updated timestamp and I want to sort using that field instead of sorting using ids.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorting will always be on the **KEYS**. 
Querying _all_docs result by query a table where the key is the _id.

```
[
  {
    "key": "my_first_id",
    "value": {}
  },
  {
    "key": "my_second_id",
    "value": {}
  }
]
```

So if you want to sort on another field than **_id**, you will need to use Map/Reduce([Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html)) For example, you could create a view where the key is the **updatedAt** field. 
This would result in something like this :

```
[
  {
    "key": "1475858068",
    "value": {}
  },
  {
    "key": "1475553268",
    "value": {}
  }
]
```

So using the sort would result by sorting the key :)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think you understand the question as a whole. Yes your solution works but what I want to achieve is sort + pagination. The pagination technique I described above requires a unique "key" to serv as the bookmark for the next page and I simply cannot use timestamp alone as key.

Comment: There a multiples techniques of paginating as described [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/pagination.html). All of them can be used with my solution. When you have a view, you always have a minimum of 3 properties (id,key,value). Using the view, you will be able to sort correctly **and** still have the possibility to get the last id for paginating.